# Git Bash and new line

Tags: git, bash, ifs

So,
People have often asked why I am not such a fan of linux, well here'e why.
In Windows programming a \n is a \n.  period.  there is no other interpretation.  But in linux bash, who knows what you're going to get.

for example:
every thing i look up online says that:
IFS=$'\n'

will split on new line.
so will someone please explain to me why this:

```
local OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
local status=$(git status --porcelain 2> /dev/null)
#I even added this just in case:
status=$( status )
#but no matter what length is always 1
local length=${#status[@]}
echo $length
IFS=$OIFS
```

echos the value of 1 when I know for certain that the git status in this repository returns 7 lines of data?
I've tried, $(echo -en "\n\b"), I've tried just "\n" (which seems funny enough to split on new line but also on just the letter n.)
It's like standardization doesn't exist in linux.  I can run the same script several times and get different results.

All I want, is a script that takes the porcelain results of git status, splits it on the new line, and then splits it on the space for each line.
this would create a an array of arrays, that look like:

```
[0] "M","modfile.cs"
[1] "A","addfile.cs"
[2] "??","newfile.cs"
```

but IFS does not seem to EVER want to handle a carriage return.  In other commands I was able to fix this because they had -printf or --pretty arguments that I could change the split char on.  But get status i only newline and so far, bash script can't split on new line.

Any ideas?
Thanks
Jaeden "Sifo Dyas" al'Raec Ruiner

PS tell your editor that I decide what is code, not it.

Comment: You should really read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting

Comment: The start and end of this post read more like a rant than a question.

Comment: For what it's worth, this has nothing to do with Git and everything to do with bash. Declare `status` as an array and the code sample you gave works (well, with `status=($status)` that is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting confused by bash syntax (which, admittedly, is a bit of a mess). The problem is that `var=(some stuff)` and `var=$(some stuff)` do completely different things. `var=(some stuff)` sets `var` as an array. `var=$(some stuff)` runs `some stuff` as a command, captures its output, and stores that in `var` *as a plain string, not an array* (and not split with `IFS`). If you want to create an array from the output of a command, you need to combine both: `arrayvar=( $(some stuff) )`. So this should work:

```
local OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
local status=( $(git status --porcelain 2> /dev/null) )
IFS=$OIFS
#but no matter what length is always 1
local length=${#status[@]}
echo $length
```

Note that I moved the `IFS=$OIFS` command earlier in the sequence, because the splitting you want it to control happens in the `status=( stuff to be split )` line, and having a nonstandard `IFS` set any longer than necessary can cause weird effects. Also, I completely removed `status=$( status )`, since it discards the previous value of the variable (/array) `status`, and replaces it with the output of the command (*not* variable) `status`, treated as a plain string (rather than an array). Not what you wanted at all.